# Difference between `share()` and `publish().refCount()`

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

What's the practical difference between `observable.publish().refCount()` and `observable.share()`. What would be an example of an scenario in which we don't want to use `share`?

Comment: [tag:System.Reactive] is a .Net tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no practical difference, if you look at 'observable.prototype.share' you will see that it simply returns 'source.publish().refCount()'.

As to why you would want to use it, it is more a question of how much control you need over when your source starts broadcasting.

Since `refCount()` will attach the underlying observable on first subscription, it could very well be the case that subsequent observers will miss messages that come in before they can subscribe.

For instance:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 5).share();

var sub1 = source.subscribe(x => console.log("Observer 1: " + x));
var sub2 = source.subscribe(x => console.log("Observer 2: " + x));
```

Only the first subscriber will receive any values, if we want both to receive them we would use:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 5).publish();

var sub1 = source.subscribe(x => console.log("Observer 1: " + x));
var sub2 = source.subscribe(x => console.log("Observer 2: " + x));

source.connect();
```

Comment: With rxjs 5 there is a difference between the two usages of the operator. See [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1363) I posted to the rxjs 5 repo for a detailed explanation of the differences

Comment: @Christian I am currently facing an Issue in an Angular2 application. I have an `Observable` of a http-request with multiple `Observer`s. The developer-tools of my browser record about 750 requests for a task. When i change `share()` to `publish.refCount()` there are only 50 requests left for the same task. So it seems like `share()` is not doing what it should (share the `Observable`).

Comment: Also see this issue for the differences https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1914

Comment: The share() example means that the first range() result is synchronous, meaning it's not possible to have a race condition where both subscribes receive a value?

Comment: Not sure how the situation was that long time ago, but looking at the Stackblitz, it behaves different now, compared to the answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cdragb

Answer (score 8):

According to article "[Rxjs Observable publish refcount vs share](https://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/09/03/rxjs-observable-publish-refcount-vs-share/)";

> With observable.publish().refCount(), **once the observer completes, it
>   will not restart if a new subscriber** is added after completion.
>   Whereas with observable.share(), if the underlying observer completes
>   and a new subscriber is added later, the **observer effectively begins a**
>   **new execution** and starts emitting data.